# How to convert mmm d yyyy HH:MM[AM] to datetime in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am going nuts with `datetime` and SQL Server.

I have (example) `Aug  4 2011 12:00AM`

How do I convert this to a `datetime` (or `smalldatetime`) type.

```
convert(datetime, 'Aug  4 2011 12:00AM')
```

EDIT: it works

Thanks.

Comment: where are you getting that date from?

Comment: its loaded by system into an nvarchar field. I need to grab it from one table and use it in another. The process that puts it there is external and no way to modify it to put into normal format, nor can I touch the table i am getting it from . SIGH

Comment: What isn't working?  I just tried your line, and I'm not getting any errors (on SQL Server 2005 SP2).

Comment: Your syntax is correct. What error are you getting?

Comment: Agreed, what you have should work according to [this](http://linesofcode.net/snippets/45).

Comment: i messed up the column order in my insert statement. sigh. i need sleep. sorry guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *does* work for me on SQL Server 2008.

```
select convert(datetime, 'Aug  4 2011 12:00AM') as ConvertResult

ConvertResult
-------------
2011-08-04 00:00:00.000
```

What's happening is an implicit conversion, though, not always trustworthy. The format specifier for your date format is `100`, found in the table on the [CAST and CONVERT docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx). Try this:

```
select convert(datetime, 'Aug  4 2011 12:00AM', 100) as ConvertResult

ConvertResult
-------------
2011-08-04 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: hah I should have checked to see if it worked before typing all that crap.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way ?

```
convert(datetime, 'Aug  4 2011 12:00AM', 120)
```

120 is for style formatting.

Check this link for full documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can "massage" the data a bit: (Warning: not tested, but something along these lines should work).  As a note, this is a brute force method if no other way works.

```
declare @datestring varchar(30);
set @datestring = 'Aug  4 2011 12:04AM';

select convert(datetime, 
    substring(@datestring, 8,4) + '-' +
    case lower(left(@datestring, 3))
        when 'jan' then '01'
        when 'feb' then '02'
        when 'mar' then '03'
        when 'apr' then '04'
        when 'may' then '05'
        when 'jun' then '06'
        when 'jul' then '07'
        when 'aug' then '08'
        when 'sep' then '09'
        when 'oct' then '10'
        when 'nov' then '11'
        when 'dec' then '12'
    end + '-' +
    right('00' + ltrim(rtrim(substring(@datestring, 5, 2))), 2) + ' ' +
    substring(@datestring, 13,50)
) as Converted;
```

Comment: +1 for trying to help me!! thanks